# How to avoid autoconfigurable classes loading while Running Springboot Testcases

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, junit-runner

I am Currently facing the problem while running spring boot test.I have a spring boot project with vaadin and micro services configuration,When I run the test cases then behind the hood automatically some auto configurable classes are being loaded and the test take more amount of time to start and run.So is there any way I can avoid loading of the auto configurable classes so that I can quickly start my project.

My requirement is I must be able to get the Application context without loading the bunch of auto configurable classes.

I am using the just the two annotations above my class that is

@Runwith(SpringRunner.class) and 
@SpringbootTest

And I am getting the following things while running the test cases which I want to avoid is there any quick and short solution for excluding these things

2019-05-15 12:01:04.583  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
2019-05-15 12:01:05.789  WARN [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/abd/prod/master": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2019-05-15 12:01:05.804  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] com.abc.ui.view.login.LoginTest   : The following profiles are active: prod
2019-05-15 12:01:05.820  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@91f565d: startup date [Wed May 15 12:01:05 IST 2019]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3c5dbdf8
2019-05-15 12:01:09.458  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'propertyPlaceholderConfigurer' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=propertyTestConfiguration; factoryMethodName=propertyPlaceholderConfigurer; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/abc/ui/test/base/PropertyTestConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [com.abc.ui.config.UIConfiguration]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=propertyPlaceholderConfigurer; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/abc/ui/config/UIConfiguration.class]]
2019-05-15 12:01:09.459  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'messageSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.vaadin.spring.i18n.config.I18NConfiguration; factoryMethodName=messageSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/vaadin/spring/i18n/config/I18NConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=UIConfiguration; factoryMethodName=messageSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/abc/ui/config/UIConfiguration.class]]
2019-05-15 12:01:09.460  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'feignFormEncoder' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=multipartSupportConfig; factoryMethodName=feignFormEncoder; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/abc/ui/config/MultipartSupportConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=fileManagementServiceProxy.MultipartSupportConfig; factoryMethodName=feignFormEncoder; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/abc/ui/services/filemanagement/FileManagementServiceProxy$MultipartSupportConfig.class]]
2019-05-15 12:01:09.572  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'WEBAPIGATEWAY.FeignClientSpecification' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2019-05-15 12:01:09.573  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'WEBAPIGATEWAY.FeignClientSpecification' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2019-05-15 12:01:09.578  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'WEBAPIGATEWAY.FeignClientSpecification' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2019-05-15 12:01:09.579  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'WEBAPIGATEWAY.FeignClientSpecification' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2019-05-15 12:01:09.589  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'WEBAPIGATEWAY.FeignClientSpecification' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2019-05-15 12:01:09.589  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'WEBAPIGATEWAY.FeignClientSpecification' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2019-05-15 12:01:10.294  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2019-05-15 12:01:10.573  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2019-05-15 12:01:10.887  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'environmentWebEndpointExtension' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.env.EnvironmentEndpointAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=environmentWebEndpointExtension; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/env/EnvironmentEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.LifecycleMvcEndpointAutoConfiguration$EndpointConfiguration; factoryMethodName=environmentWebEndpointExtension; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/LifecycleMvcEndpointAutoConfiguration$EndpointConfiguration.class]]
2019-05-15 12:01:11.542  WARN [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'com.vaadin.spring.VaadinConfiguration' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2019-05-15 12:01:12.098  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=532f1489-08d5-38dd-bf71-f959f522990c
2019-05-15 12:01:13.098  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2019-05-15 12:01:13.270  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'UIConfiguration' of type [com.abc.ui.config.UIConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$49f61c00] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:13.312  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService  'getAsyncExecutor'
2019-05-15 12:01:13.312  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'getAsyncExecutor' of type [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:13.798  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.annotation.SleuthAnnotationAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.annotation.SleuthAnnotationAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3442aec2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:14.265  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'sleuthAdvisorConfig' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.annotation.SleuthAdvisorConfig] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:14.493  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4df76b8d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:14.524  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.log.SleuthLogAutoConfiguration$Slf4jConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.log.SleuthLogAutoConfiguration$Slf4jConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b8458f71] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:14.559  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TraceFeignClientAutoConfiguration$FeignBeanPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TraceFeignClientAutoConfiguration$FeignBeanPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$716f4156] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:14.841  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.AsyncDefaultAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.AsyncDefaultAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$19c114af] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:14.908  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f48bf0d6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:14.974  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.TraceWebClientAutoConfiguration$RestTemplateConfig' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.TraceWebClientAutoConfiguration$RestTemplateConfig] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:15.002  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceHttpAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceHttpAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$185b71df] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:15.037  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.TraceAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.TraceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6ada85a3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:15.114  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConversionServiceDeducer$Factory' of type [org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConversionServiceDeducer$Factory] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:15.121  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.sleuth-org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.SleuthProperties' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.SleuthProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:15.158  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'sleuthPropagation' of type [brave.propagation.B3Propagation$1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:15.191  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'slf4jSpanLogger' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.log.Slf4jCurrentTraceContext] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:15.208  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'noOpSpanReporter' of type [zipkin2.reporter.Reporter$1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:15.227  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'sleuthTraceSampler' of type [brave.sampler.Sampler$2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:15.340  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'sleuthTracing' of type [brave.Tracing$Default] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:15.358  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'sleuthHttpTracing' of type [brave.http.AutoValue_HttpTracing] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:15.608  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'tracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor' of type [brave.spring.web.TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:15.611  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.TraceWebClientAutoConfiguration$RestTemplateConfig$TraceInterceptorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.TraceWebClientAutoConfiguration$RestTemplateConfig$TraceInterceptorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$32d296e1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-15 12:01:15.968  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing FeignContext-WEBAPIGATEWAY: startup date [Wed May 15 12:01:15 IST 2019]; parent: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@91f565d
2019-05-15 12:01:15.995  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2019-05-15 12:01:17.756  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing FeignContext-COUNTRY-SERVICE: startup date [Wed May 15 12:01:17 IST 2019]; parent: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@91f565d
2019-05-15 12:01:17.782  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2019-05-15 12:01:20.605  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/chat/delete-conversation],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.abc.ui.controller.ChatController.deleteConversation(com.telintel.services.conversationservice.integration.dtos.ConversationDTO)
2019-05-15 12:01:20.607  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/chat/push-conversation],methods=[POST]}" onto public void com.abc.ui.controller.ChatController.postConversation(com.telintel.services.conversationservice.integration.dtos.ConversationDTO)
2019-05-15 12:01:20.608  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/chat/push-message],methods=[PUT]}" onto public void 
2019-05-15 12:01:21.501  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2019-05-15 12:01:22.719  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:59) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted

2019-05-15 12:01:23.299  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2019-05-15 12:01:24.583  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2019-05-15 12:01:26.112  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map)
2019-05-15 12:01:26.114  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map)
2019-05-15 12:01:26.116  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2019-05-15 12:01:27.151  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2019-05-15 12:01:27.308  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.v.spring.i18n.CompositeMessageSource   : Looking up MessageProviders
2019-05-15 12:01:27.323  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.v.spring.i18n.CompositeMessageSource   : Found 1 MessageProvider(s)
2019-05-15 12:01:27.324  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.v.spring.i18n.CompositeMessageSource   : MessageFormat cache enabled
2019-05-15 12:01:27.405  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] .s.i.MessageProviderCacheCleanupExecutor : Message provider cache cleanup is disabled
[heartbeatInterval] = [300]
2019-05-15 12:01:30.233  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [closeIdleSessions] = [false]
2019-05-15 12:01:30.278  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Forwarding @SpringUI URLs from {/=org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@5d3b0f8a}
2019-05-15 12:01:30.285  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController]
2019-05-15 12:01:31.108  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter   : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@91f565d: startup date [Wed May 15 12:01:05 IST 2019]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3c5dbdf8
2019-05-15 12:01:31.186  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2019-05-15 12:01:31.187  INFO [abc,,,] 11976 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[POST],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity

Comment: You should only use `@SpringBootTest` if you want to run an integration test. If you want to test a single component don't use `@SpringBootTest` but just create the component, mock the depenencies and run the test.

Comment: @M. Deinum I need the Application context which will not be available just by SpringbootTest as I have Enable I18N in my configuration class which I need to compare text and all.

Comment: Why? That is basically testing if Spring is working and not your own code. If you really want you could even create your own `ApplicationContext` with your subset. You don't have to use `@SpringBootTest`, because, as mentioned, that is for integration testing.

Comment: please provide sample application if possible and explicit requirement what you need to achieve. https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=SomeAutoConfiguration.class)` in order to exclude some classes that you don't need to autoConfigure in your test environment.

More information you will find [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-exclude-auto-configuration-test).

Comment: I have lots of configuration classes for micro services then It would be a long list of classes can you just mention that what classes I need to have as spring boot test case that only I can mention here or like similar of thing because excluding a long list of classes might be not a good solution.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, but you should try to configure a BaseTestContext or something like that, where you exclude and include classes that you want and after that, create concrete TestCases that extends BaseTestContext. This is the way I'm working.

Comment: the testCase runs fine but as I have provided some logs here I am using spring microservices, There are many Auto configurable classes which are in the springs list might be loading for the container but as we know we don't need any extra configurable classes where the topic comes to microservices and test case the only thing I need is I can run my test cases light weight without any extra loading of classes and neglecting a huge number of Auto configurable classes as my application is too large spring is taking much time to load the test cases.